# p5.js creating a new Vector error

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

So i'm trying to rewrite some of main proccessing sketches to p5.js, but (there is always a but..) i have a problem with creating Vecotrs. I think i'm lacking some simple java script uderstanding here.

So i use the example provided with p5.js, and my code looks like that:

```
var location ;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  background(0);
  location = new Vector(0, 0);
  //location = createVector(0, 0); 
  //location =  new p5.Vector(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
 ellipse(location.x, location.y, 80, 80);
}

function Vector (x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = x;   
}
```

I tryied 3 ways of creating vectors, the one right now, with creating custom "class" Vector, and those 2 commented out. And if i try it out, i have page not found and address bar is changed to "address to my index.html/p5.Vector%20Object%20:%20[0,%200,%200]".

I really have now idea what is wrong.

Comment: You're setting `window.location`.

Comment: oh my, you are right, changing the name of the variable did the trick o_O. Thank you.

Comment: Don't edit your question. Post an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable name was the culprit. I was actualy accessing **window.location** . Simple name change did the trick.

Comment: Fun tip: If you use `let` instead of `var`, you get a nice error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of non-configurable global property location` pointing right to the line.